# Getting an error in JSON Import with python "string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, indices

```
import json

json_dump = json.dumps('1.json')

json_object = json.loads(json_dump)

print(json_object["client_id"])
```

I am writing a code in python which extracts email id from a json file.
But I am getting an error :-

> " string indices must be integers "

Here is the JSON FIle i am importing :-

```
  {
  "type": "Some Data",
  "project_id": "Some Data",
  "private_key_id": "Some Data",
  "private_key": "Some Data",
  "client_email": "Some Data",
  "client_id": "Some Data",
  "auth_uri": "Some Data",
  "token_uri": "Some Data",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "Some Data",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "Some Data"
  }
```

Comment: Your code does not load the file, it just converts the filename (not the file) to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should first open the file, and pass the opened file in `json.load(file)`

```
import json
# opening the json file
json_file = open('1.json','r+')

json_object = json.load(json_file)

print(json_object["client_id"])


Output:
Some Data
```

for looping over json files named as numbers

```
import json
# opening the json file
# files named as 1.json to 3.json will do this
for i in range(1,4):
    json_file = open(str(i)+'.json','r+')

    json_object = json.load(json_file)

    print(json_object["client_id"])
```

Comment: Thank you soo much It works now !!!
I have one more question. I have multiple json files with numbering from 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.
How can I make a loop to call them and extract email from everyone of them ?